# jquery .each loop on array with parseInt - gives NaN

Tags: jquery, json, each, parseint

I have setup a loop using `.each` to get json encode string to an array to be used for jquery jqBarGraph

The loop:

```
     $.each(dataarray, function (i, item) {
         JSarray[i] = [parseInt(item['count']),parseInt(item['year'])];                        
     });
```

The data in the dataarray contains a json string  =

```
    {"graph":{"count":"45","year":"2007"}}
```

after `.each` loop contains these values in the JSarray

```
    [45, 2007]
```

So a single string works, when i try to pass more data I get the vale NaN

If I try to use this json encode string in the data dataarray the NaN comes

```
{"graph":[{"count":"45","year":"2007"},{"count":"390","year":"2008"}]}
```

My JSarray looks like this

```
[NaN, NaN]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You now have an array list instead of a dict for the property of "graph". You need to update the $.each method

Comment: thanks so much - I just have not yet got my head around the array and objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
{"graph":[{"count":"45","year":"2007"},{"count":"390","year":"2008"}]}
```

The `graph` property now contains an array. You will need to iterate over that to parse your ints.

I would try this...

```
$.each(dataarray.graph, function(_, obj){
  JSarray.push([parseInt(obj.count), parseInt(obj.year)]);
});
```

Keep in mind, a regular `for` loop would be best as `$.each` is a little expensive for this.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked as a charm - I really need to get my head around objects and arrays

Comment: @user1557970 you're welcome. If this answer worked for you please accept it. If not, please consider accepting one of the other answers to show your appreciation. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :

```
$.each(dataarray.graph, function (i, item) {
  JSarray[i] = [parseInt(item['count']),parseInt(item['year'])];                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
$.each(dataarray['graph'], function (i, item) {
  JSarray[i] = [parseInt(item['count']),parseInt(item['year'])];                        
});
```